# mysql backup only those table which has changed in a day

Tags: mysql, backup

I have created a replica of my production server to a test environment. I hav backed up my prod db and restored it to test but i dont want data to be dumped to test server everyday.

Is it possible I can identify which tables has changed and only dump data which has been inserted for that day.

Please let me know if I am being unclear in the description what I want to do.

Thanks,
Manasi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the --log-bin parameter is enabled on the servers, you can do incremental backups http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the best method but you could just have a "last modified" field and look to see if any of the fields are of the current date.